# MariaDB root password change using Ansible

Tags: mariadb, password, mariadb-10.1, root, ansible

I had tried to change MariaDB root password using following Ansible script.

```
      - name: Dump MySQL root Password
        debug:
          msg: "MySQL new Password : {{ mysql_pass }}"

      - name: Set MySQL root Password
        become: True
        mysql_user: 
          name=root
          host="localhost"
          password="{{ mysql_pass }}"
          check_implicit_admin=yes
          login_user="root"
          login_password=""
          state=present
```

In my `/etc/ansible/hosts`

```
[myhosts:vars]
mysql_pass=mynewpassword
```

As I was [told](https://www.reddit.com/r/ansible/comments/kmyv9t/install_galeria_mariadb_cluster/) password variable may not be taken, I added `debug/msg` step.

```
TASK [Dump MySQL root Password] ********************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [vizua@node1] => {
    "msg": "MySQL new Password : mynewpassword"
}
```

Similar issue discussed [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/102066/ansible-how-to-change-mysql-server-root-password-by-reprovisioning-the-server). Thats where I got Password changing steps. This step runs without error, showing `changed`, but yet I can access without password or any password.

MariaDB : `Server version: 10.1.47-MariaDB-0ubuntu0.18.04.1`
Ansible : `ansible 2.5.1`

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your yaml is wrong (`=` instead of `:`).

I'd study the docs for mysql_user (`ansible-doc mysql_user`) and check the examples to get an idea.